# How to save Spark model as a file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm testing out the document code at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/mllib-ensembles.html#random-forests. For some reason, myRandomForestClassificationModel was saved as a directory. How do I save it as a file? I'm new to Spark, so I'm not sure if I did anything wrong in the code.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest, RandomForestModel
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils

sc = SparkContext(appName="rf")
# Load and parse the data file into an RDD of LabeledPoint.
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, '/sample_libsvm_data.txt')
# Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

# Train a RandomForest model.
#  Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
#  Note: Use larger numTrees in practice.
#  Setting featureSubsetStrategy="auto" lets the algorithm choose.
model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                     numTrees=100, featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                     impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)

# Evaluate model on test instances and compute test error
predictions = model.predict(testData.map(lambda x: x.features))
labelsAndPredictions = testData.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)
testErr = labelsAndPredictions.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(testData.count())
print('Test Error = ' + str(testErr))
print('Learned classification forest model:')
print(model.toDebugString())

# Save and load model
model.save(sc, "/rf/myRandomForestClassificationModel")
sameModel = RandomForestModel.load(sc, "/rf/myRandomForestClassificationModel")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code. It is correct that models are saved as a directory, specifically there is a `model`and `metadata` directory. This makes sense as Spark is a distributed system. It's like when you save data back to hdfs or s3 which happens in parallel, this is also done with the model.